# Reset state of synced CouchDB

Tags: synchronization, couchdb, backup, distributed, pouchdb

We use CouchDB and PouchDB to have in browser replications of a remote database.
We create backups of the CouchDB in case something ever goes wrong.

Introducing a backup when data is lost is no problem, but resetting the system to a older state which should also affect all synchronized PouchDB seems to be very difficult to achieve.

As an example: `User1` and `User2` synchronize a local PouchDB with a remote CouchDB. `User1` creates a new document `D1` which is also synced to the remote database and to `User2`. Now `User1` wants to reset the database to the state before `D1` was created. To achieve this, the user deletes the own local database and resets the remote CouchDB to the previous state. When `User1` synchronizes with the remote CouchDB, the `D1` wont be there. But `User2` still has `D1` in his local database and once this is synced with the remote database, `D1` will also be back on the CouchDB and synced to `User1`'s local database. Eventually the system is in the same state as before it has been reset.

For our project it is impractical to ask every user to delete the local databases before the system can be backed up.

How could a procedure looks like that would reset such a distributed system into a older state.

Some additional challenges:

- The example is rather simple and should just give a general idea what is happening. In the end there might have been a big number of create, edit and delete operations that have to be undone with the backup.
- Some of the clients might be offline when the system reset happens

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is no easy way out. Some options are:

1. Don't actually delete databases. Instead, adjust your restoration method such that all documents in the to-be-restored DB are deleted and then individually recreated as in the backup. You could compare the revisions/ use the `_changes` feed to filter out docs that may remain unchanged.
2. Programmatically delete other users' local databases before attempting to sync in case a restore was made.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why the Database has to be restored from a previous state when deleting a document - normally a deleted DB entry gets deleted on other synced clients as well.

But I have a very similar setup where I have to delete the CouchDB on a regular basis and set up a new one. What I do is sending a signal to each client that triggers the automatic deletion of his local PouchDB and reconnect to the DB. Works great.

Comment: Maybe my example is a little bit to simple. The goal is that we want to be able to fully restore the database and all local copies to a previous state. This will not always be as easy as just deleting some files but might include a big number of edits, deletes and creates that have to be undone.
Your solution sounds interesting, how do you handle cases where the client PouchDB might be offline when the signal is sent?

Comment: I set a variable at the "Server-Application" (my Program works a bit different). Every time a client reconnects he asks for this variable. If it is different from the one he has got it means there is a new CouchDB and he deletes his PouchDB and sets the new server variable as his own.